# need to filter data for `dataBefore` by comparing with 'dataAfter'

Tags: c#

I have 2 list where I need filter data from `dataBefore` if not matching `Name` and `SectionId` available in `dataAfter` list.

```
var dataBefore = new List<School>
        {
            new School { Name = "N1", SectionId = null },
            new School { Name = "N2", SectionId = new Guid("6aba7a38-8e61-472d-b4ce-b9fc2011af3f") },
            new School { Name = "N3", SectionId = null },
            new School { Name = "N4", SectionId = new Guid("ca663d45-04b8-4c80-96b6-c3760352a6ac") }
        };

        var dataAfter = new List<School>
        {
            new School { Name = "N1", SectionId = new Guid("5be0fc99-4826-4fbf-a190-b930af730b93") },
            new School { Name = "N3", SectionId = null },
            new School { Name = "N4", SectionId = null }
        };
```

Expected output should be,

```
 //N1  with sectionId = null
        //N2 with SectionId = 6aba7a38-8e61-472d-b4ce-b9fc2011af3f
        //N4 with SectionId = ca663d45-04b8-4c80-96b6-c3760352a6ac
```

Below query give me exact opposite result (only `N3`), how to get above expected result?

```
 var x = dataBefore.Where(y => dataAfter.Any(z => z.Name == y.Name && z.SectionId == y.SectionId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = dataBefore.Where(y => !dataAfter.Any(z => z.Name == y.Name && z.SectionId == y.SectionId)).ToList();
```

You can get the result if the Any() returns false.